# Fields with Multiple Entries in Views w/ External Data Source

Tags: views, database

I'm on drupal 7.9 and I'm using the Views 3 rc1. I've successfully created a custom base table that draws data from an external database (a drupal 6 site's database). Here's that code:

```
<?php
function etlo_mod_views_data() {

//define the content_type_workshop table from the drupal 6 site.
//set it as the base table
$data['content_type_workshop']['table']['group'] = t('Workshops');
$data['content_type_workshop']['table']['base'] = array(
'field' => 'nid',
'title' => t('ETLO Workshops'),
'help' => t("External Etlo Database"),
'weight' => -9,
'database' => 'www2',
);

 //define the node table from the drupal 6 site
$data['workshop_node']['table']['group'] = t('Workshops');

//define the content_field_workshop_category table from drupal 6 site
$data['content_field_workshop_category']['table']['group'] = t('Workshops');


//define the content_field_workshop_grade_level table from drupal 6 site
$data['content_field_workshop_grade_level']['table']['group'] = t('Workshops');


//Link the workshop node table (for getting the title) to the contenty_type_workshop table
$data['workshop_node']['table']['join']['content_type_workshop'] = array(
'table' => 'node',
'left_field' => 'nid',
'field' => 'nid',
);

//Link the workshop category table (for getting the title) to the contenty_type_workshop 
$data['content_field_workshop_category']['table']['join']['content_type_workshop'] =     array(
'left_field' => 'nid',
'field' => 'nid',
);

//Link the workshop grade level table (for getting the title) to the     contenty_type_workshop table
$data['content_field_workshop_grade_level']['table']['join']['content_type_workshop'] = array(
'left_field' => 'nid',
'field' => 'nid',
);



// Define the 'workshop_shortname' field.
$data['content_type_workshop']['field_shortname_value'] = array(
'title' => t('Short Name'),
'help' => t("The course's shortname."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
),
);

//define the 'NID' field.  Probably not needed.  Was just testing.
$data['content_type_workshop']['nid'] = array(
'title' => t('NID'),
'help' => t("the workshop nid."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
),
);

//define the description  
$data['content_type_workshop']['field_workshop_description_value'] = array(
'title' => t('Workshop Description'),
'help' => t("The course's description."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
),
);


//define the title - from the node table
$data['workshop_node']['title'] = array(
'title' => t('Workshop Title'),
'help' => t("The course's full course name."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
),
);


//define the grade level - from its own table 
$data['content_field_workshop_grade_level']['field_workshop_grade_level_value'] = array(
'title' => t('Workshop Grade Level'),
'help' => t("The course's grade level."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_in_operator',
'options callback' => 'etlo_mod_grade_level_handler_callback',
),
);

//define the category - from its own table 
$data['content_field_workshop_category']['field_workshop_category_value'] = array(
'title' => t('Workshop Category'),
'help' => t("The course's category."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_in_operator',
'options callback' => 'etlo_mod_category_handler_callback',
),
);

//define the delta - from the field_workshop_category table 
$data['content_field_workshop_category']['delta'] = array(
'title' => t('Category Delta'),
'help' => t("The entry's delta."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',

),
);


//define the delta - from the field_workshop_category table 
$data['content_field_workshop_grade_level']['delta'] = array(
'title' => t('Grade Level Delta'),
'help' => t("The entry's delta."),
'field' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
'click sortable' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
),
'filter' => array(
'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
),
);
return $data;
}
```

Everything there works very well. It allows me to bring in the data from the other database, and I also configured a couple of option callback functions that successfully set values for a couple of filters.

The big problem that I'm having has to do with multiple values in a single field on the drupal 6 site that we're connecting to. On that site, both the 'category' and 'grade_level' fields can have multiple values. When I have this situation, I usually use the "Multiple Field Settings" settings box that shows up when you add a field in the views UI to combine them into a single entry. In my case, that settings panel doesn't show up. I am using the normal 'views_handler_field' handler for these fields...should I be using something else? How can I combine multiple field values into a single views row when the data comes from an external database?